# Dialogflow - Get answer to security question

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am building an agent that will initiate a conversation with a caller.  After asking basic information the agent will need to get a security phrase or secret from the caller to establish they are who they say they are.

I cannot get the agent to capture the answer after the agent asks, "what is your security phrase".

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Can you update your question to show what you've tried and why they aren't working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a custom follow-up to the intent requesting the security phrase.
2. In the custom fullow-up training phrases, insert a parameter associated with the @sys.any entity that allows you to capture any sentence.
3. In the fullfilment call the parameter and verify if the security phrase given by the user is the correct one.

But be careful, this solution is simple but not always safe. The follow-up helps you to give the right direction to the conversation, but if the user says a sentence that matches an intent without input context, the conversation could accidentally continue in a wrong way. This is because using @sys.any makes difficult (or impossible) to throw a fallback intent for an unexpected response.